# How wearing a gem(ratna) distract bad woes/trouble?

Tags: belief, karma, astrology

In `Hinduism` we consider `Karma` as supreme and your good/bad mainly depends on `karma`, then how do wearing certain gems can impact destiny/trouble/good/bad etc. ?

Is it only a marketing strategy by certain people or there is some solid reference provided in the scripts regarding this that how do they slow down or distract the bad things to happen ?

Comment: you can ask this question on the Jyotisha SE proposal to get a more detailed answer: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101512/jyotisha?referrer=WNGAY2D0NY672-MEPBo36A2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scriptures do not describe how they do it, but they do describe that wearing certain gems give benefits like destruction of sin, protection from snakes, etc. For example, consider the following verse of the Garduda Purana:

> *teṣu rakṣoviṣavyālavyādhighnānyaghahāni ca
>
>   prādurbhavanti ratnāni tathaiva viguṇāni ca* [GP - 1.68.8]
>
> **Meaning**
>   Among the gems some protect against poisons, snakes, diseases and expiate sins. And some others also contain demerits.

Just like in Ayurveda certain herbs and plants are known to have beneficial effects, so also in astrology certain gems and stones are known to have good effects. But scriptures describe they must be delicately prepared  and should be genuine in order to work. So good gems may not change fate or destiny of a person, but they do have some level of positive influence upon the bearer as per the scriptures.

Answer (score 3):

Vaidika [remedies](http://jyotishavedika.blogspot.in/2005/10/remedies-in-astrology-how-do-they-work.html) can be classified broadly into **maNi**, mantra and auShadha.

***maNi*** is the remedy involving gems and precious stones. It is mainly used to build the psychological strength and will power of a native suffering with problems. There are different gems prescribed for different planets in jyotiSha and the use of respective gem pacifies the planet causing troubles or strengthens the planet at weak position in the horoscope. But this is not a magic or illogical remedy that is to be laughed at. This kind of remedy prescribes:

-usage of gems in ornaments

-usage of gems in medicines(since gems are metallic compounds)

-usage of gems in dAna(charity, donation)

-usage of gems in worship and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if [Brihat Parashara Hora Shastra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brihat_Parashara_Hora_Shastra), which is a foundational text of astrology has any such references. Although, *Upaya* or providing remedial measures is considered a part of Jyotisha. Many astrologers do recommend gems as a remedy. I believe they do have some minimal effect but not a lot. Also, this might provide some insights:

> Q: In astrology many astrologers recommend wearing certain gem stones
>   and rings. Do you recommend wearing those things and if you are on the
>   spiritual path do you need to wear those things?
>
> Sri Sri Ravi Shankar: No you don’t need to, of course everything
>   has some influence on you but you know you are much more
>   powerful than a piece of stone. So if you like you can do it.
>   Otherwise chant ‘Om Namah Shivaya’, that is most powerful mantra which
>   takes care of all the bad effects of any planets.

Reference used: http://wisdomfromsrisriravishankar.blogspot.in/2011_05_01_archive.html

Answer (score 1):

There are nine types of gems, according to the Rasaprakāśasudhākara, which is a 13th-century Sanskrit literary work related to Medical Alchemy, or Rasaśāstra (Rasa literature).

1. Manikya(Ruby)
2. Mukta (Pearl)
3. Vidruma
4. Tārkṣya (Emerald)
5. Pusparaga (Topaz)
6. Vajra (Diamond)
7. Nila or Nīlamaṇi (Sapphire)
8. Gomeda (Hessonite)
9. Vaidurya(Cat’s eye)

The Ratnas of superior quality and possessing better physical characteristics may only prove to give all types of siddhis (success). And only such ratnas (gemstones) should be used for dana (offering purpose), Rasayana (therapeutic purpose), dharana bearing purpose, and devarchana (worship of Gods).

In astrology wearing these stones is considered auspicious but in Ayurveda, these are utilized for both Rasayana (therapeutic purpose), and Dharana bearing purpose and are indicated in Various disorders.

- Ratna (रत्न):—Precious Stones.
- Ratna (रत्न) in the Rigveda and later denotes a precious object, not specifically a ‘jewel’, as in post-Vedic literature. [source](https://archive.org/details/vedicindexofname01macduoft)
- Ratnā (रत्ना, “Jewel”):—Fifth of the eight Mātṛs born from the body of Śaśinī, according to the Kubjikāmata-tantra.
- Ratna (रत्न) refers to “jewels”, according to the Halāyudhastotra verses 34-35. [source](https://brill.com/view/title/56613)
- Ratna (रत्न) refers to “precious gems”, representing the material of the Brahmāṇī’s liṅga, according to the Śivapurāṇa 2.1.12. [source](https://archive.org/details/SivaPuranaJ.L.ShastriPart1)
- Ratna (रत्न) refers to “ruby” and represents a kind of precious stone (gem) used for the making of images (Hindu icons), as defined in the texts dealing with śilpa (arts and crafs), known as śilpaśāstras. [source](https://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/handle/10603/5089)
- Ratna (रत्न) refers to “precious stones”, according to the Bṛhatsaṃhitā (chapter 15) (“On the nakṣatras—‘asterisms’”) [source](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brihat-samhita)

Comment: [Avoid Overt Self Promotion](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)